# cake php find all with join returns even non matching data. How to fix it?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have Three tables Projects, Tasks and Tags. Projects.id is the primary key of the first table, Tasks.id is the PK of the second table and Tags.id is the PK of Third table.

Projects Model Code snippet

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $hasMany = array(
    'Tasks' => array('className' => 'Tasks','foreignKey' => 'project_id')
);
```

Tasks Model Code snippet

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $hasMany = array(
    'Tags' => array('className' => 'Tags','foreignKey' => 'task_id')
);
```

The below query return some unexpected result.

```
    $joins = array(
        array('table' => 'project_tasks',
            'alias' => 'Tasks',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Projects.id = Tasks.project_id'
            )
        ),
        array('table' => 'task_tags',
            'alias' => 'Tags',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Tasks.id = Tags.task_id',
                "Tags.tag_name = 'Driver'"
            )
        )
    );
    $data = $this->Projects->find('all', array(
        'recursive' => 2,
         'joins' => $joins
    ));
```

The response data i am getting is

```
 [Projects] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [project_id] => 1234
                    [project_name] => XYZ
                )

            [Tasks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [project_id] => 1
                            [task_id] => 12
                            [task_name] => task1
                            [Tags] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [task_id] => 1
                                            [tag_id] => 3444
                                            [tag_name] => Driver
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [project_id] => 1
                            [task_id] => 343242
                            [task_name] => task2


                            [Tags] => Array
                                (
                                  [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                            [task_id] => 2
                                            [tag_id] => 4444
                                            [tag_name] => Doctor
                                        )
                                )

                        )
```

See i am even getting tasks without tag as Driver.  How i can exclude tasks without tag Driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by specifying 'fields' to be selected and setting       'recursive' => -1 as show below.

```
     $data = $this->Projects
                    ->find('all', array(
                          'recursive' => -1,
                          'joins' => $joins,
                         'fields' => array(
                             'Projects.*',
                             'Tasks.*',
                             'Tags.*'  
                          )
));
```